# How can i make ruby save the same randomly generated title into a txt?

Tags: ruby

I got a great response from you guys for how can i save a methods text into a txt file, but i encounteres a different problem now. The thing is that the program generates a random title and prints it in the command prompt, but it saves a completely random title in the file. For example if i run the program it will generate a title "Big Thing", but in the txt file it will save "Small Game". Is there a way to make the program save the same title as it prints in CP? The code looks something like this:

```
class Generator
  def title_adj
    title_adj = [
       "Big",
       "Small"]
    item_title_adj = title_adj[rand(title_adj.length)]
  end
  def title_noun
    title_noun = [
       "Thing",
       "Game"]  
    item_title_noun = title_noun[rand(title_noun.length)]
  end
  def title
    title_adj + title_noun
  end
  def initialize(io)
    @io = io
  end
  def all
    @io.puts "Your story is called: " + title
  end
end

fict_gen = Fiction_Generator.new(STDOUT)
def prompt
  print "> "
end
puts "Do you want to generate a new title or read the existing one?"
puts "1 = Generate, 2 = Read existing"

prompt; r = gets.chomp
if r == "1"
  fict_gen.all

  File.open("Story.txt", "a+") do |file|
    fict_gen = Fiction_Generator.new(file)
    fict_gen.all
  end

elsif r == "2"
  File.open("Story.txt").each_line{ |s|
  puts s
  }
end
```

Comment: Wow, refactoring help needed on aisle six! STAT!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are randomly generating the title each time you call the method. Prove this yourself:

```
a = Generator.new(STDOUT)
a.title #=> "BigThing"
a.title #=> "SmallThing"
a.title #=> "BigThing"
```

The solution, store the title in an instance variable:

```
def title
  @title ||= %w|Big Small|.sample + %w|Thing Game|.sample
end
```

The `||=` operator only performs an assignment if the receiver is `nil` or `false`.